# php count the number of strings after exploded

Tags: php, arrays, count, explode

Here is my code

```
<?php

$string = 'a|b|c|d|e|f';

$tags = explode('|' , $string);


foreach($tags as $i =>$key) {
$i >0;
    echo $i.' '.$key .'</br>';

}

?>
```

the output is

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
5 f
```

What i'm try to count the number of strings after i exploded | (it should be 6  for my example) also i need my $i to start from 1 not 0

Any idea please ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you normally do to `count()` items in an array?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = 'a|b|c|d|e|f';

$tags = explode('|' , $string);


foreach($tags as $i =>$key) {

    echo $i.' '.$key .'</br>';

}

?>
```

Try using:

```
echo count($tags); // Output of 6
```

Arrays start with a key of 0, not one. So when using anything else apart from count, you will constantly get 1 less than your expected (unless you modify the array prior to counting)

Comment: If you create a simple array: `$Var = array("First","second");` then issue `print_r($Var);` you will notice the keys will always start at 0. This is the primary index for every created array. hence you getting the output you have got. You would need to re-index your array before your loop but after creating the array to get keys as: `array(1,2,3,4,5,6);`

Comment: Re-index the array?? Why not simply add 1?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 I was thinking of the array displaying aspects aswell

Answer (score 9):

If you just need the total number, you could do this:

```
$tags = explode('|' , $string);
$num_tags = count($tags);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$string = 'a|b|c|d|e|f';

$tags = explode('|' , $string);

$count =count($tags);
  echo 'Count is: '.$count .'</br>';
$i = 1 ;
foreach($tags as $key) {

    echo $i.' '.$key .'</br>';
$i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = 'a|b|c|d|e|f';
$array= explode('|' , $string);
 for($i = 0;$i<count($array);$i++){
  echo $i. $array[$i]."\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

programmers always count from 0, it's good practice, but if you really need to do this simply declare the $i variable as 1 before the fooreach loop

Comment: "programmers always count from 0" actually it depends on the language